# Salesforce internet speed for end user?

Tags: community

Is the internet speed of 2mbps enough to run Salesforce for 200 users? We are about to implement Salesforce and around 200 users would be going live. I am a little afraid as the internet speed is low. What is the approximate speed so that the users dont face issues?

Comment: Salesforce is on cloud. SO is your all user will access from same place or they will use it from different place. Also what they will do on SF. are they dev or just end user?

Answer (score 4):

If you're running an office of 200 users on a 2mbps connection you're going to be in for a bad time, but that's probably a moot point because I can't imagine you'd be getting *anything* done online with that kind of setup.

I'm assuming that you're not in that position and that you simply mean you're rolling it out to 200 users over a wider geographical area (at least, not 200 users sharing one 2mbps connection).

Salesforce is cloud based software, the servers are not in your building and they are what the users' browsers will be communicating with. If your office has a slow line it'll only affect the users that are inside of that office. Other user's experience will be determined by their own connects.

For what it's worth, in my experience latency is more of an issue than the connection speed. Working on a developer org in Europe from Australia is pretty painful on any connection, yet saving code to the same org from London on a 1mbps line was a far more enjoyable experience.

Answer (score 0):

See [Salesforce Bandwidth Requirements](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004958&language=en_US). In general each page is only about 90kb, however, the "main" portion of salesforce (style sheets, JavaScript, and so on) will initially take up much more bandwidth. This usually means that logging in will be notably slow on a 2Mbit pipe, but casual browsing of records should be fairly smooth. However, this only applies if you use the default caching settings for your browser. If the cache is abnormally small or large, or disabled entirely, your users will have a very poor experience using the system. Also keep in mind that some activities are very intensive, such as uploading attachments, importing large files, etc. If this will be a common occurrence, I'd suggest upgrading your bandwidth.